# Is there a PDF viewer for Flutter 3.3.8 version?

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-dependencies, flutter-plugin

do you know to exist any pdf viewer plugin to be compatible with Flutter 3.3.8 version?

What I already tried was pdf_viewer_flutter and flutter_full_pdf_viewer, but these are incompatible because of the new V2 embedding of Android

Comment: try this https://pub.dev/packages/syncfusion_flutter_pdfviewer

Comment: Be aware that the SyncFusion products in the Dart/Flutter pub are *not* open source.  They are released under a commercial license that may subject you or your organization to a financial liability, and might affect downstream re-users of your code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use this pacakge:

https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_pdfview

flutter_pdfview: ^1.2.5